# Aligning a Acronym Glossary

Tags: vertical-alignment, glossaries, acronyms

I have a simple Acronym glossary using the following code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{uri}{URI}{Unique Resonance Identifier}
\newacronym{led}{LED}{light-emitting diode}
\newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically TESTICLE programmable
read-only memory}

\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]
\begin{document}
No acronyms here.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

this produces the following output:

[image: capture]

I would however like everything to be properly aligned, eg have the same amount of space from the Abbreviation to the full name. any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would setup a custom style in a tabular format so that you can control spacings and contents of your summary list

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{longtable,floatrow,booktabs}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{uri}{URI}{Unique Resonance Identifier}
\newacronym{led}{LED}{light-emitting diode}
\newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically TESTICLE programmable
read-only memory}

\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]

\newglossarystyle{custom_acronyms}
{
    \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%  
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \textbf{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}
        & ##2
        \tabularnewline}%
}

\begin{document}
No acronyms here.

%\printglossaries
\printglossary[type=acronym,style=custom_acronyms]
\end{document}
```